# Service account access to SharePoint online

Tags: iis, asp.net, sharepoint

I've got a ASP.NET web site, which runs in a custom app pool using an AD service account. The web site which is only available on the internal network is supplied by a third party vendor, as such we don't have access to the source code to modify it.

Since moving from SharePoint Server to SharePoint Online, we've discovered that the service account can no longer access SharePoint.

All the server code does is find a matching document on SharePoint by hitting five different url's and then rendering a hyperlink to first one that returns a 200 response. However it no longer finds a matching document as it receives 403 instead of a 200.

The service account has been given access to SharePoint Online and has access to the site where the documents live.

Any ideas on how we can make this work?

Comment: SharePoint Online uses a completely different authentication mechanism, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/authentication So you shouldn't expect your old code to work magically. Please modify the web site accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @LexLi, unfortunately we don't have access to the source code,question updated accordingly.

Comment: Then I suggest you don't waste time on this. Either find a way to get the source code, or you give it up.

Comment: Seriously @LexLi? Somehow I don't think this is an option, thanks for your input, hopefully someone else might be able to provide a more helpful answer.